# WEB.CONFIG - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

this topic has already appeared on the forum, but not as exactly as for me and I did not find an answer.

Hosting shows me this error.

> The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. (`D:\HostingSpaces\sieniutest\sieniutesting2.hostingasp.pl\wwwroot\web.config line 25`)

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
                <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="mycon" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" name="MySQLMembershipProvider" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordFormat="Clear" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
                <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
                <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
            <providers>
                <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
                <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <webParts>
            <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
                <providers>
                    <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
                    <add applicationName="/" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=8.0.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
                </providers>
            </personalization>
        </webParts>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
        <add connectionString="c1" name="LocalMySqlServer" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Full error details:**

```
The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. (D:\HostingSpaces\sieniutest\sieniutesting2.hostingasp.pl\wwwroot\web.config line 25).
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
 at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. (D:\HostingSpaces\sieniutest\sieniutesting2.hostingasp.pl\wwwroot\web.config line 25)
 at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
 at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
 at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeSettings(Boolean initializeGeneralSettings, RuntimeConfig appConfig, MembershipSection settings) at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
 at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Providers()
 at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.PreAppStartInit()
 at WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()

Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String&amp; keyname, String&amp; keyvalue)
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
 at MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(String connectionString) at MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString, NameValueCollection config)
 at MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config)
 at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
```

Comment: You don't have a connectionstring named "mycon" in there.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you help me, where should I add this? I have this string 'mycon' in other .cshtml file

Comment: Looks like you have one named "c1" instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I've changed this value to "c1", same error

Comment: @MacMax Well,, **of course** it will cause an error because `"c1"` is not a valid MySQL connection string value.